# How do I get 12 kills/knockouts on the Moira Asylum level?

Tags: thief

In Chapter 5, aka, the Moira Asylum level, how do I complete the optional predator objective of obtaining 12 kills? There are a grand total of 11 killable mobs in the whole level. Is there a secret area with a den of crazies that I missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you first enter the area with the freaks, you will see an animation with a freak running away from you. This freak will disappear in a hole in the wall. If you are quick enough, you can shoot it with a blast arrow and get an additional kill. AFAIK this is the only way to achieve the 12 kills/knockouts in this chapter.

Comment: I am not going to test it since I've already 100%'ed the achievements in this game, but this sounds very plausible.